# Nested React route is not displaying content

Tags: reactjs, nested, dropdown, router

I am using React 4 and have a top level component that issues a route like this

```
            <Route path={testingUrl}>
                <TestingPage />
              </Route>
```

The TestingPage component is

```
   import React from "react";
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
   import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
   const history = createBrowserHistory();
   const DropDown = () =>  {
     const onChange = (e) => {
       history.push(`/aaa/testing/${e.target.value}`);
     }
       return (
         <select onChange={onChange}>
           <option value="first-route">First</option>
           <option value="second-route">Second</option>
         </select>
       );
   }
   const Menu = withRouter(DropDown);
   export default function TestingPage() {
     return (
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div>
           <Route path="/aaa/testing/first-route" render={() => <h1>First Selected</h1>} />
           <Route path="/aaa/testing/second-route" render={() => <h1>Second Selected</h1>} />
           <Menu />
         </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
     );
   }
```

I select the second item in the dropdown, the URL is correctly updated to '/aaa/testing/second-route', but the "Second Selected" is not displayed. I do not understand why.

Note that I do not want to do anything that would lose the content of the React context.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that thr DropDown component is using a different 'history' to the one that is being watched for changes by the BrowserRouter.

If you want your dropdown to use the same history as BrowserRouter, you need it use the prop passed by withRouter instead of creating a second one with createBrowserHistory.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const DropDown = props => {
  const {history} = props;
   
  const onChange = (e) => {
     history.push(`/aaa/testing/${e.target.value}`);
  }
  return (
    <select onChange={onChange}>
      <option value="first-route">First</option>
      <option value="second-route">Second</option>
    </select>
  );
}
const Menu = withRouter(DropDown);
```

If you absolutely need to use a custom history object (for example if you are passing a base URL) then you need to pass it to the BrowserRouter when you create it, not to the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks David, I do not need a custom history object. If I remove that history definition , I get "history.push is not a function" error. I do not seem to have access to the history object, without that const history.

Comment: In order to use withRouter, the component needs to be created inside the BrowserRouter. Otherwise there won't be a history in the context for you to use.

Comment: It looks like it did not include all the code . I have the menu in the BrowserRouter., is that what you mean : ```const Menu = withRouter(DropDown);

export default function TestingPage() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route path="/aaa/testing/first-route" render={() => <h1>First Selected</h1>} />
        <Route path="/aaa/testing/second-route" render={() => <h1>Second Selected</h1>} />
        <Menu />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}```

Comment: Yes. It should work like this https://codepen.io/davidgeorgeuk/pen/abNqrxM

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou David , I had missed passing though history on the drop down. Changing to
const DropDown = ({ history }) => {
worked :-)